# Java - MySQL-StoredProcedure not executed

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures

I call a few stored procedures from within my java class. Only one of these stored procedures seems not to be called, but no exception is thrown. The stored procedure looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `insertLoggingMessage` (IN userName VARCHAR(50), IN softwareId   VARCHAR(100), IN operationName VARCHAR(100), IN msg VARCHAR(1000), IN lvl VARCHAR(10))

BEGIN
    SELECT id INTO @userId FROM benutzer WHERE name = userName;
    INSERT INTO logging (benutzer_id, software_id, operation_name, message, level)
    VALUES (@userId, softwareId, operationName, msg, lvl);
END
```

The java code, that runs the query, looks like this:

```
private void logToDatabase(Authentication auth, String operationName, String message, LoggingLevel level) {
  String software = getSoftwareId(auth);
  String query = "CALL insertLoggingMessage(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
  try {
    connect(this.dataSource);
    CallableStatement statement = this.conn.prepareCall(query);
    statement.setString(1, auth.getUserName());
    setNullableStringParameter(statement, software, 2);
    statement.setString(3, operationName);
    setNullableStringParameter(statement, message, 4);
    statement.setString(5, level.name());
    statement.execute();
    disconnect();
  } catch (Exception exc) {
    logToFile(auth, "logToDatabase", exc, level);
  }
}
```

The code is executed without an exception. When I call the stored procedure via HeidiSQL, it works fine.
So why is the stored procedure not executed via the CallableStatement? I'm really desperate now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround. I declared the variable in the stored procedure before setting the value via the select statement. This works.

```
DECLARE userId INT(10);
SELECT id INTO userId FROM benutzer WHERE name = userName;
INSERT INTO logging (benutzer_id, software_id, operation_name, message, level)
VALUES (userId, softwareId, operationName, msg, lvl);
```